# Slenders Head In A Door?

Tags: slender-haunt

I was playing Slender Haunt and just came back into the game, all was normal until I turned my head and Slender had his head in the door!  Also I lose almost instantly as soon as I see him in the door. :(  This only seems to happen if I turn towards the door when the beginning static is playing and it still doesn't happen all the time.  I haven't heard about this from anyone else so maybe it is just a problem with the download of the game but I am still wonder:  Was That A Glitch, and how can I fix it if it is?

"I may be Slender but I still run into problems (Or A Door) like you mortal" ~ Mark Slender

Comment: It's not clear from your question: is this a clipping error, with Slender's head through a closed door? Maybe a screenshot would be helpful?

Comment: I'm not really sure I just know this isn't right.  He also has his hand stuck through the door and some of his tentacles have somehow disappeared.

Comment: So yes, his model is going through the solid door? That sounds like it's pretty clearly a glitch.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix this problem?  Do you play Slender Haunt?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to understand your question. If a non-player can understand the situation, that means a player definitely can, and you have a better chance of getting useful answers.